# SQL Server 2008 - need help merging 2 tables (cartesian)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have 2 tables that are not related at all and I need to put them together - one column per table. When I try the cartesian join, I end up with every combination:

```
SELECT Field1, Field2 FROM Table1, Table2
```

Result:

```
Table1.Field1 Table2.Field2
---------------------------
1             1
1             2
1             3 
2             1
2             2
2             3
3             1
3             2
3             3
```

I need it to return side-by-side:

```
Table1.Field1 Table2.Field2
---------------------------
1             1
2             2
3             3
```

is this possible? Thanks in advance

***EDIT***

```
Table1.Table1IDs
----------------
1
2
3
4
5

Table2.Table2IDs
----------------
6
7
8
9
10
```

Desired output (into a temp table/select statement)

```
Table1.Table1IDs    Table2.Table2IDs
------------------------------------
1                   6
2                   7
3                   8
4                   9
5                   10
```

So that I can then do my insert into the actual table I need to do an insert:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.MTMObjects
    SELECT Table1IDs, Table2IDs 
    FROM [temp table or solution]
```

***ANSWER***
Bluefeet gave me the idea to use temp tables with an identity column that i can then use to join.  His is 'safer' because you aren't relying on SQL's good humor to sort both recordsets the same, but this might help the next guy:

```
DECLARE @tmp_Table1 TABLE(ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, TableID1 int NOT NULL)
DECLARE @tmp_Table2 TABLE(ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, TableID2 int NOT NULL)

INSERT INTO @tmp_Table1 
    OUTPUT INSERTED.Field1
SELECT * FROM Table1

INSERT INTO @tmp_Table2 
    OUTPUT INSERTED.Field2
SELECT * FROM Table2

OUTPUT
SELECT tmp1.Field1, tmp2.Field2 
FROM @tmp_Table1 tmp1 INNER JOIN @tmp_Table2 tmp2 ON tmp2.ID = tmp1.ID
```

CHEERS!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try something like this using `row_number()`. This will force a relationship between the two tables based on the `row_number`:

```
select t1.col1, t2.col2
from
(
  select col1, row_number() over(order by col1) rn
  from table1
) t1
inner join
(
  select col2, row_number() over(order by col2) rn
  from table2
) t2
  on t1.rn = t2.rn
```

## See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3c727/2)

Comment: I ended up using a variation of this - i'll post it above so the next guy will have 2 solutions :)

Comment: @Losbear you can always post your version as an answer and then accept it as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

if i understood ...the only you need is to add a filter in where clause

```
SELECT Field1, Field2 FROM Table1, Table2 WHERE Table1.Field1=Table2.Field2
```

Comment: The two tables are COMPLETELY unrelated - they each have a single column with IDs in them.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably change your final solution to use an outer join instead of inner join, in case the tables don't have exactly the same number of rows.